# Problemas con dispatch dentro de react y en la carga del payload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

tengo problemas con react. Me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto el cual estamos utilizando contextos a travez de useReducer. El mismo falla al momento de cargar un dispatch. A continuacion mostrare un ejemplo de codigo al momento de utilizarlo.

````
```
dispatchBodyData({
                    type: 'SET_BODY_DATA',
                    payload: response.response
                });
                dispatchRenderState({
                    type: 'SET_RENDER_CONDITION',
                    payload: bodyData,
                    component: 'IncidenciaDialog',
                    condition: 'bodyData_condition'
                })
```
````

Como pueden ver, el segundo dispatch trata de cargar su payload "bodyData", este mismo seteado en el primer dispatch "dispatchbodyData", pero por motivos que desconozco bodyData nunca se alcanza a setear antes de pasarse por el payload del segundo dispatch

Comment: Podes agregar el componente completo? Puede que sea un problema de asincronia

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de escribir. Con respecto a tu pregunta, como mucho ese dispatch lo coloco dentro de un useEffect. y antes de invocar al dispatch defino su metodo reducer para utilizarlo usando un contexto. Mi problema lo encuentro al momento de que se carga los datos. Y es que sea posible que el error este por el lado de la Asincronia, entonces como podria resolver o controlar eso? muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrias usar Promesas, pero sin un poco mas de contexto, es difícil asegurar que el problema sea la asincronía, lee [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Si, pasa que no puedo enviar mucho codigo, pero bueno. El error esta que si modifico un dato que depende del otro. Al momento de ver en pantalla viene con un dato viejo. Entonces necesitaria que los datos se cargaran al mismo tiempo, entonces capaz a alguien capaz paso por lo mismo.